# Should the commit history be used to convey critical information to developers?

Tags: version-control, documentation

During a meeting regarding the rollback of a third-party SDK from the latest version it was noted that the our developers already flagged in the commit history that the latest version should not be used.

Some developers argued that this was a bad practice and it should have instead been noted either in the source file (i.e. `// Don't upgrade SDK Version x.y.z, see ticket 1234`) or in a project level `README` file. Others argued that since the commit history is part of the project documentation it is an acceptable location for such information since we should all be reading it anyway.

Should the commit history be used to convey critical information to other developers or should such information be duplicated to another location such as a project `README` or comments in the relevant source file?

Comment: It sounds like your project has pretty serious communication problems.

Comment: Do you require new hires to go through the entire commit history?

Comment: New hires should not be rolling through the code base and changing dependencies without specific direction to do so.

Comment: @Midnotion So somewhere on the path from new hire to main developer you take time to go through the entire commit history? Fascinating.

Comment: On the path from new hire to lead dev, you need to take the time to understand the system and the reasons why it is that way.  Let's face it, few real projects are thoroughly documented, and of those that are, there is so much to read that no new hire could be expected to understand it all.

Comment: That still doesn't make it a good idea to put critical information solely in the commit history.

Comment: Updating to the latest version of an SDK can be a pretty large change. This is probably something that should have been discussed as a group before being checked in.

Comment: @Midnotion Yeah, that's entirely true. I think word of mouth sort of does the trick in the end, hopefully. However, the log in the commit history probably didn't help that process, it's more about discussion and emails etc. I don't think its an bad idea in addition to telling your colleagues btw, because people sometimes check these things when they're struggling with something.

Comment: In the light of more recent answers, please reconsider your selection of accepted answer. Trying to document away this problem has significant risks. There is no better documentation than a passing or failing test. Although it is outvoted by over 8:1, [Karl Bielefeldt's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/251874/22493) is is by far and away the best answer here.

Comment: @MarkBooth I think that answer existed back when I accepted the accepted answer. I upvoted Karl's answer but wasn't a fan of having a unit test because it presupposes that a problem is easily unit testable. Plus, you would still need to have the problem documented somewhere else anyway since most people aren't going to read unit tests to find out that they shouldn't upgrade until *after* the test fails which wastes valuable time.

Comment: Fair enough, I was thinking more integration test than unit, and software isn't always easy, but I've been in this situation before and consider it a *belt, braces and a piece of string* situation: try to prevent with documentation (not that programmers ever read it), with comments in the code/dependencies (not that they are always visible if using an GUI or auto dependency tool) and detect with a test, just in case both are missed.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

If I was going to look at upgrading to a newer version of a third party SDK, the last place I'd look is in the *history* of the source control system.

If your product is using version 2.0 of an SDK and someone is interested in upgrading to 3.0, I don't think it's reasonable to think that they should look backwards in time in your source control system to find out that it's not a good idea.

Here, we have a team wiki that has a handful of pages with interesting info that every developer reads (coding conventions, how to set up a development environment to build the product, what third party stuff you need to install, etc).  This is the sort of place that would be appropriate for a warning against upgrading a third party library.

Comment: Indeed, the commit history is the *history* of the project. Just like it would be stupid to have crucial information in the *history* of wiki edits, and not on the actual page itself. History (whether code or wiki) is for reference on what happened previously, not on what should happen now.

Comment: If possible for the fictional SDK, I would add a unit test designed specifically to pass under V2 and fail under V3 with an explicit assert statement giving the reason not to upgrade to V3. The commit history is a good place to state why you're making that one change for code reviewers, not for documenting best practice.

Comment: @Klors As long as you don't restrict yourself to the most pedantic definitions of unit tests and refuse to do other types of automated tests, a test based on checking the file system/etc for the libraries name (if it has the version encoded in it) or a hash/checksum of the file itself could be used to throw a red flag at anyone wanting to update the library even in cases where the new versions flaw is difficult/impossible to capture in a test.  (eg multi-threaded race conditions)

Comment: @Klors I was thinking the same thing, but in my opinion, the unit test should demonstrate the *reason* for using v2 over v3, that way if the unit test passes with v4, you don't have a unit test that requires v2 for no reason.

Comment: Another reason not to use the commit history for this: the commit history is a permanent record.  If the reason for not upgrading goes away, the commit history is still going to contain the warning not to upgrade, which could be confusing.  You need somewhere where lists of requirements like this are kept up-to-date, so that developers don't have to double check whether things are still relevant.

Comment: @Matthew has given the, IMO, best answer. A unit test that fails in V3 because of whatever in V3 doesn't work with your stuff. If it gets fixed in V4 or the implementation of your stuff changes  to work with V3, the unit test will tell you.

Comment: The flaw with relying on a unit test for documenting this is that you don't find out until *after* you've done the upgrade.  I just upgraded one of our third party libraries today and between downloading, installing, and licensing the new library and updating all of the references to the new assemblies, it was at least a couple of hours of work before I could even compile.

Comment: We have a source code file that checks all the version numbers at run time. If the numbers don’t match, QA _cannot_ overlook it. So after upgrading a library, you have to modify this file. That would be an excellent point for a comment warning you not to upgrade.

Answer (score 70):

It should be noted in the commit history but the absolute best place to put the notice is in the same place you define the dependency. If you have for example a maven .pom file that declares your artifact dependencies, I'd do something like:

`<!-- Do not change the SDK version because it causes Foo crashes. For more detail see Issue #123 -->`

Directly above your `<dependency>` line.

Issue #123 would include details about how it crashes, the version you updated to that caused the crashes, and it probably should then get added to your backlog again for revisiting later - it's possible that there's a yet again newer version that fixes the issue. Either automatically by editing the ticket, or manually yourself, it will email the team to let them know about the current issue now, and by being in the tracker it lets people find it again later.

The reason to put it with the dependency declaration is because whoever wants to change the version will see it at the moment they want to change it and understand why they shouldn't.

I wouldn't comment in the source code because I can easily picture a situation where someone runs a check on your dependencies and starts upgrading them. They should not need to scour the codebase for every TODO comment to do that.

Linking to the issue ticket lets a curious developer know how it failed and potentially revisit it later. Without that, it might become fairly static and never be updated again.

Comment: I agree: the best location for critical information is "in as many places as possible." Maybe the `pom.xml` or equivalent project file, a readme, etc. but the commit history is still good. If I am looking at upgrading a library I may check the history of the existing version to see when it was updated as well as any notes about issues the committer had. But I would not want to go digging through the history to gather all the documentation. It is a good _supplementary_ source.

Answer (score 35):

Critical and non-intuitive pieces of information should be documented where people will be looking when considering the information.

For the teams and projects I've worked on, I would commit the roll-back with the comment about why the new version failed. I would add a backlog story to re-try the upgrade if the new version get's fixed. I would add comments to the build system/build scripts where the library is linked.

The roll-back will provide future developers with context when looking into the project's history. The backlog story keeps the need for this upgrade as an active part of the project. The build system comments are right where the changes will need to be when the library is finally updated.

I would not comment it in the code and I would not add it to a README. Developers thinking about trying the upgrade will not be looking at these pieces. If you do add it there, then when the issue with the library is eventually fixed and an upgrade is done, you will need to remove it. This step is often forgotten: resulting in notes that are counter productive to the project.

---

If your project has a different setup or a different flow, then your answer may be different. I think the key is to put the information right were the developer will see it when doing the work for the upgrade. That way, if the time is not right for the upgrade, the developer will see it and stop, and when the time is right the developer will see it and remove the note so it won't confuse future developers.

Comment: Yes, the comment needs to be placed "in the path" of the change. So  it's technically impossible to do the action without seeing the warning. It's a lot like safety controls.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to create a story/ticket for the upgrade in your issue tracker, set to "On hold" with an explanation of why it can't be done yet. The issue tracker is one place you really _can_ reasonably require people to look before working on something.

Comment: +1 Quoting Jeff Attwood (although he talks about, ugh, "users"): "The next time you're designing [X], consider [client] myopia. You might be surprised just how myopic your [clients] can be. Think long and hard about placing things directly in front of them, where they are not just visible, but unavoidable. Otherwise they might not be seen at all."
http://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/

Answer (score 17):

I wanted to give [Matthew's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251587/should-the-commit-history-be-used-to-convey-critical-information-to-developers#comment505183_251596) more attention by highlighting his important idea in an answer.  There's a reason why you don't want to upgrade your SDK, and that reason should be captured in a unit test.  Not a check for a revision number, but the actual underlying reason.

For example, say there's a bug in the new version.  Write a unit test that checks for that bug.  If they later fix that bug in the SDK, then the upgrade will occur smoothly.  If there's an incompatible API change, write a test that checks that either your code supports the new API or the SDK supports the old API.  That's more of an integration test than a unit test, but should still be doable.

My company generates 50+ commits per day, and we're not exactly huge.  Even if every developer read every single commit message, which let's be frank they don't, the whole reason we need a recorded commit history is because people can't remember it.  And people don't go back and read the history later unless there's a problem.  And they have no reason to suspect a problem on an upgrade that as far as they know hasn't occurred yet.

By all means send an email to prevent duplication of work in the near term, and note it in your build scripts and a README or errata.  However, especially if the problem with the new version is subtle and time consuming to troubleshoot, you need a way of making it obvious.  That means a unit test.

Comment: This is the one true answer. Capturing the fail in a unit test prevents the bad upgrade from happening. Period.

Answer (score 15):

I'm recasting the question as "Should I communicate critical information I discover to the rest of the team only via commit message?" Because I think that makes it obvious that no, you shouldn't. I try hard to communicate a lot (this is something that most development teams, in my experience, need to put active effort into) and I certainly do everything I can to avoid creating pitfalls or letting them lie.

If the chain of actions leading me to such a discovery were triggered by a ticket, I'd update the ticket (and make sure the people who should know this have visibility), I'd probably mention it face-to-face (hoping to at least leave someone with some nagging sense that "Gee, I think Damon said something about updating that"), and I'd of course leave a comment in the code at the point the SDK was included so that no one could possibly update it without having a chance to see it. I might see if I could jam it in somewhere on our dev wiki, too, although that's done more with an eye toward future hires, not the current team.

It only takes a couple more minutes compared to the time it likely took to encounter and discover the problem. I certainly wouldn't decide that one of the least-used, low-signal pieces of our documentation and leave it at that.

Comment: +1 The real keyword is **only**. It certainly does not harm if the info is stored in a commit message **in addition** to other, more suitable places. It did hit the OP, since the commit log was the **only** documentation available.

Answer (score 13):

It should be in the commit history but it should not only be in the commit history, imagine for a moment you hire a new developer.  Do you expect that new developer to read every commit message for the past 10 years of your project because a couple of them will be critical to understanding your code base?

Second say the situation but not the code changes, are you going to make "documentation" commits so that you can add commit messages along the lines of "commit message from revision 5432 is now incorrect, here is the current situation."

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how your team communicates but I believe the most effective way to say this is to *first* send and email to the team's email group, marked as "URGENT" with the body saying

> Guys, we can't use SDK v x.y.z because it causes the Foo buffer to overflow and the Bar service will crash. Stick with version x.y.y

That's what we've done here and it's the most reliable way to get the message out there. If you *really* want to be fussy (and if your email system allows it), request a "read receipt" on the email.

Once you've told the whole team, more detailed documentation should be put into a team wiki. This will vary, depending on how you structure your documentation. If you have a section specifically for your applications Dependencies and Requirements, that would be a good place to add it.

An additional place to document this sort of problem might be in the source code itself, although that might not always work. If `SDK version ...` is only referenced in one or two obvious places, you could include a note about not upgrading.

The file history in source control can be very long, and depending on the developers, could have several entries per day. Someone who's been out on vacation for a week might not have time to read a week's worth of commit history. The README file is a better place as it's a little more central and people might be more inclined to read it, but you can't ensure that everyone will actually *read* the README. Well, I suppose they *might* if they see it's been changed...

Comment: I like the email group idea. Too many places I've worked rely on individual addresses and things are not passed on to new members.

Comment: What happens if somebody new comes to your team?  Who is responsible for giving them this kind of pseudo-institutional knowledge?

Comment: @ABMagil: The information goes into a wiki. Developers who are new to the team are usually started of there, on some introductory pages. Then they come to specific individuals (who have made time available for helping the new dev) when they have specific questions (and they always do). For us, it would probably end up in the "Developer Setup Guide for ApplicationX" as `NOTE: Do not use SDK vers. x.y.z because...` but the initial communication should be an email.

Comment: -1 emails don't work well as documentation

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Email provides a simple and easy-to-use method to let everyone on the team know *immediately* that a problem has been discovered in using a specific version of a specific library and that this version should not be used. As stated, long-term documentation is best done in a team's wiki or some other sort of knowledge base.

Comment: @ABMagil mailing list with a history might be a lazy "solution" for this.  If you think about it, it seems to work for many open source projects.

Comment: Having looked at many and contributed to some open source projects, I disagree that mailing lists work as a source of information.

Comment: You wouldn't expect a new programmer to read two years of mail from a mailing list.

Comment: @Daenyth: I don't think email is the *only* place to document this, I think it's the best tool to send the initial notification of the problem to all people who *might* encounter it themselves if not immediately warned.

Comment: @user119591: No, I wouldn't. If the problem happened *two years ago* and was *still* a problem today, it would be documented in a team wiki, and new developers would read about it there when they're setting up their workstation.

Comment: I removed my -1 since this now suggests the wiki rather than the email. I think it could be structured better to emphasize that the main point is to put it in the wiki, but at least it mentions it now

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should have been put in the commit comments, but it will benefit from being in other places as well.

Whoever makes the decision to upgrade, needs to have the facts. That person may not live in source control. What if someone would have read about this problem on SO and never put it into the code base?

There needs to be some sort of document about this third-party SDK.

- What problem does it solve?
- Why was this particular one chosen?
- What considerations need to be made as far as: versions, upgrades, testing, etc.
- Who makes this decision?

You have a case where something like this made its way into the version control, and you should recommend everyone use this information as much as possible. Only your team can decide where someone is going to do a search in any documentation, source control, or bug tracker to get as much information as possible on the subject. Otherwise, you'll forget, someone will do it anyway, and you'll be lucky if it jogs someone's memory and quickly roll it back again.

Answer (score 2):

History is a great place to put data intended for a reader who is consciously looking for it, and has a general sense of where it should be.  It is a very bad place to put data which must be proffered to a user, rather than searched for.

Histories are very large bodies of relatively unsorted text.  They are usually intended to provide a developer with detailed information about what changed, and why it was changed.  This can be information overload unless one knows what they are looking for.

If a user does not know what they are looking for, then the information is quickly buried under hundreds of commit logs, and they have no tool to prune down the pile of information in front of them.

Comment: this reads more like a comment than an answer. See: [Answer]

Comment: Good point, I expanded it.  Hopefully this meets StackExchange's criteria better.

Comment: I think this answer best addresses the topic of the question.  Commit history is good for saving info if a person knows they should be looking for a note.  If there is no reason to examine the 'blame' for a given line, such as the inclusion of an SDK, then that documentation won't be read.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret this situation as having two basic problems, possibly three.

- An unwanted SDK upgrade made it into the source, where it could negatively affect the product.
- From the question: the contributor who performed the unwanted upgrade didn't know about a previous, specific decision not to upgrade.

The first of these, in my opinion, is the most serious.  If an unwanted SDK upgrade can make it into the code, so can other problems.

Someone suggested adding a unit test case that will fail if it detects the upgrade.  While it would prevent the upgrade from occurring, I believe this is a dangerous path, leading to [lava flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava_flow_%28programming%29) over time.  It seems inevitable that at some point in the future the SDK will be upgraded, to bring in new features or bugfixes, or because the old version is no longer supported.  Imagine the head-scratching, maybe even arguments, that will occur when such a unit test then fails.

**I think the most general solution is to adjust the development process.  For git, use the [pull request](https://www.google.com/search?q=pull%20request) process.**  For Subversion and older tools, use branches and diff.  But have *some* process that allows the senior developers to catch these kinds of issues *before* they make it into the codebase and affect other developers.

If the pull request process had been used in your situation, and if each pull request is narrow and specific, not much time would have been wasted.  A pull request to upgrade the SDK would have been submitted, and declined with comment that the upgrade is not wanted.  No one else would have been impacted, and there would be no need now to revert the SDK upgrade.

But to directly answer the original question, I agree with others that expecting all developers to fully read the entire revision history of the code, release notes, etc. for notices like this is a waste of valuable time.  What's wrong with a short team e-mail?

Possible third issue: Why is the upgrade not wanted in the first place? Clearly at least one developer thought the upgrade would be a good thing. There are many good reasons to delay an upgrade, but also many bad ones.  Take care to avoid the lava flow (unnecessary backwards-compatibility code) and [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) ("we can't upgrade that, but I don't know why") anti-patterns!

Comment: While the SDK upgrade, which was a minor version number as opposed to major, was what ultimately lead to this question, this line of reasoning has been popping up in the group for awhile now.

Comment: Why would the pull request have been declined?  How is the person responsible for that decision supposed to discover (or remember) the version restriction?

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, either the team leads knew about the restriction, or *no one* remembered it and this was rediscovered after encountering problems.  Either way, using pull requests, there is no blaming the lowly new hire developer, as the seniors would approve the change before it's allowed in.

Comment: @wberry: Or a different senior developer processed the pull request from the one who knew about the version restriction.  Unless *all* pull requests have to be approved by *all* developers, which seems like a dubious expenditure of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would say adding that type of information to a commit history is ok but it still needs to be documented properly. We recently started using confluence (by atlassian). Its searchable, you can set certain pages as favorites, etc.

Some other tools might be a public notebook in evernote or google docs.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Karl's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/251874/12156), I would go with an approach that automatically enforces the restriction as part of the checkin process itself. You need something that does not require any proactive action on behalf of the developer, such as reading a doc/wiki/README, and can not be overridden covertly.

In TFS source control land you can code custom [checkin policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264876.aspx) that execute rules on checkin. For example, you could define a policy that evaluates the version in a config file with a pending checkin and will fail if it does not equal x.y.z. These rules actually prevent the developer from performing the checkin and can provide a descriptive message. The policies can be overridden, but it is possible to generate alerting when this happens.

An alternative could be gated-checkins that fail will with some form of unit test that either directly or indirectly evaluates the SDK version, as Karl mentioned.

I appreciate this answer is very TFS-centric, but possibly similar features exist in the version control/CI systems that apply in your situation (if not TFS).

Answer (score -1):

In contrast to the accepted answer, I insist commit messages are a valuable(primary) source of information.

Let's role-play a release coordinator. You are responsible for updating the current PROD version thus winning or losing a huge amount of money for the company. This is a speculation: I have never been in the position.

You check your Jira, Confluence, Artifactory, sales metrics etc. But you **also** check the last merge commits. You `grep` in your mind `I could have broken X`, `improved Y...didn't break it`(yeah, right)